# Strong coupling between steps in gherkin specs

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I am using specflow to specify my app, and it just saved me from doing really bad stuff, so I really like it :-)
However I have a problem with with the coupling between steps:
For instance since I am using mocks heavyly in one step I tell the mock that it should return an entity, but in another i tell the mock to return the same entity, but with another property.

Look at this step (stolen from Darrens answer below and modified):

```
Given a guy the following guy exists:  
| Name     | Age | Salary |  
| John Doe | 42  | 400    |  
When his salary changes to 420  
And I run the paycheck program  
Then he should be paid 420
```

See here I start with a Guy object and later modify the object - which is the thing I am testing.

So I put an entity into the mock repository, then in another step I pull it out and put it in again.
How do you avoid high coupling and reusability between steps?

Of course I could keep a local variable on the scenario class and put all the entities in that variable, but I would then couple the steps.

Answer (score 6):

The way that I avoid coupling and promote re-usability is to:

1.)  Group my steps by the entity, like AccountRepositorySteps (for AccountRepository) or AccountControllerSteps (for AccountController).

2.)  Make steps dependent on abstractions, not concretes (just like we'd do with our production code).

3.)  Lean on the current ScenarioContext to pass values between steps and step files.

Here's a short example:

```
Given a guy with the name Darren exists
And a guy with the name John exists
When I hit the guy page
Then I should see two guys
```

RepositorySteps.cs

```
private List<string> guys;

[BeforeScenario]
public void Setup(){

   guys = new List<string>();

   var fake = new Mock<IRepository>();

   fake.Setup(x=>x.GetGuys()).Returns(guys);

   ScenarioContext.Current.Set(fake) // Mock<IRepository>
   ScenarioContext.Current.Set(fake.Object); // IRepository
}

[Given("a guy with the name '(.*)' exists"]
public void a(string guy){
   guys.Add(guy);

   // and if I need to pull out the mock, I can do it like so
   var fake = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<Mock<IRepository>>(); 
}
```

GuyController.cs

```
When["I hit the guy page"]
public void x(){
   var repository = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<IRepository>();
   var controller = new GuyController(repository);

   var result = controller.Index();
   ScenarioContext.Current.Set(result);
}
```

See, here the step for the GuyController gets that mock object, but he doesn't know it's a mock.  It's just an IRepository to him.  And if, for some reason, you needed to load the REAL repository for IRepository and want to run your specs, all you have to do is load the ScenarioContext with the real IRepository.

Following this pattern, my steps are very decoupled and protected from changes I make to others.  It works a lot better than the tricks I did early in my use of SpecFlow, where I'd use static methods or group unrelated steps in the same step file.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you'd be better to split the behaviour.

```
Scenario: Change Salary

Given a guy the following guy exists:  
| Name     | Age | Salary |  
| John Doe | 42  | 400    |  
When his salary changes to 420  
Then his salary should be 420
```

And...

```
Scenario: Pay Guy

Given a guy the following guy exists:  
| Name     | Age | Salary |  
| John Doe | 42  | 400    |  
And I run the paycheck program  
Then he should be paid 400
```

They're separate units of behaviour.

Regarding shared context, the neatest solution I've come accross is dependency injection. Make some SharedContext class and inject it into the step definition classes that need the shared context. That way you can still split your step definition files however you want and they can share context. Numerous tools come with simple IoC container functionality out of the box (e.g. SpecFlow).

```
class SharedContext
{
object MyObject1 {get; set;}
object MyObject2 {get; set;}
//Etc.
}

class StepDefinitions1
{

private SharedContext _context;

public Stepdefinitions1(SharedContext context)
{
this._context = context;
}    
//Now use this._context.Properties to get at the shared objects in your 
//step definitions    
}
```

The container will take care of the rest.

Object lifecycle of SharedContext class is single scenario. I.e. for each new scenario, a new SharedContext is created and passed via constructor to all steps in classes that reference it until the final "Then" step has executed.